# Can knitr `code` option find local object?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

In [knitr manual](https://yihui.org/knitr/options/#code-chunk)

> code: (NULL; character) if provided, it will override the code in the
> current chunk

````
```{r import_x,code=knitr::include_graphics('x.png')}
png(file='x.png',width=1000,height=1000)
iris %>%
  lapply(., function(x) sum(is.na(x))/length(x)) %>%
  data.frame(.) %>%
  na.omit(.) %>%
  gather(.,factor_key = TRUE) %>%
  ggplot(.,aes(x=key, y=value))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity')+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=8,angle = 90, vjust = 0.5,hjust=1))
dev.off()
```
````

In above knitr chunk,I use `{r import_x,code=knitr::include_graphics('x.png')}` to import `x.png` and avoid creating `x.png` again.
But I got error:`Error in eval(expr,envir,enclos):cannot find object 'x.png'`

Then, I tested, `getwd()` output the expect path. `knitr::include_graphics('x.png')` in R script works well, `![ok](x.png)`works well.

Where is the problem?

Comment: Not the time for an elaborate answer ... `code` should be of type character --> `code="knitr::include_graphics('x.png')"`. Feel free so self-answer if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

As @CL 's comment,`code` option accept `character`.  `code="knitr::include_graphics('x.png')"` works well.